# PHP how to change var within multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to change the value of a field in a. multidimensional array. Note that I am not a PHP guru, I am still learning.

I am using the following structure

```
array(
      array(ID+value, GRANTED+value)
)
```

I use the following code:

```
// accept in session
foreach ($_SESSION['chatrequests'] as $request) {
    error_log("accepting chat request with id " . $request['ID'] . "  and the incoming  request is " . $requestid);
    if ($request['ID'] == $requestid) {
        error_log("matching request ids found. so granting");
        $request['GRANTED'] = "Y";
        error_log("did the granting work ???? ->" . $request['GRANTED']);

    }
}
```

The logging states the $request['GRANTED'] values is set to Y.

So after the assumed edit of the var I read out the array to see if the edit succeeded.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['chatrequests'] as $request) {
    error_log("reading chat request with id " . $request['ID'] . "  and the incoming request is " . $requestid);
    if ($request['ID'] == $requestid) {
        error_log("matching request ids found. was it granted " . $request['GRANTED']);
    }
}
```

But the $request['GRANTED'] is still set to N.

The question is how can I do this? which pattern can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal ! when do you $request['GRANTED'] = "Y";  , $_SESSION array is not modified.
You have to do :

```
// accept in session
foreach ($_SESSION['chatrequests'] as $key => $request) {
    error_log("accepting chat request with id " . $request['ID'] . "  and the incoming  request is " . $requestid);
    if ($request['ID'] == $requestid) {
        error_log("matching request ids found. so granting");
        $_SESSION['chatrequests'][$key]['GRANTED'] = "Y";
        error_log("did the granting work ???? ->" . $request['GRANTED']);

    }
}
```